# Different value when using fprintf or sprintf

Tags: matlab, function, printf

I've written a function (my first, so don't be too quick to judge) in MATLAB, which is supposed to write a batch file based on 3 input parameters:

`write_BatchFile(setup,engine,np)`

Here **setup** consists of one or more strings, **engine** consists of one string only and **np** is a number, e.g.:

```
setup  = {'test1.run';'test2.run';'test3.run'};
engine = 'Engine.exe';
np     = 4; % number of processors/cores
```

I'll leave out the first part of my script, which is a bit more extensive, but in case necessary I can provide the entire script afterwards. Anyhow, once all 3 parameters have been determined, which it does successfully, I wrote the following, which is the last part of my script:

```
%==========================================================================
%   Start writing the batch file
%==========================================================================

tmpstr = sprintf('\nWriting batch file batchRunMPI.bat...');
disp(tmpstr); clear tmpstr;
filename = 'batchRunMPI.bat';
fid      = fopen(filename,'w');

fprintf(fid,'set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1\n');
for i = 1:length(setup);
    fprintf(fid,'mpiexec -n %d -localonly "%s" "%s"\n',np,engine,setup{i});
    fprintf(fid,'move %s.log %s.MPI_%d.log\n',setupname{i},setupname{i},np);
end
fclose all;
disp('Done!');
```

**NOTE** ***setupname*** follows using ***fileparts***:

```
[~,setupname,setupext] = fileparts(setup);
```

**However**, when looking at the resulting batch file I end up getting the value 52 where I indicate my number of cores (= 4), e.g.:

```
mpiexec -n 52 -localonly "Engine.exe" "test1.run"
mpiexec -n 52 -localonly "Engine.exe" "test2.run"
mpiexec -n 52 -localonly "Engine.exe" "test3.run"
```

Instead, I'd want the result to be:

```
mpiexec -n 4 -localonly "Engine.exe" "test3.run", etc
```

When I check the value of **np** it returns **4**, so I'm confused where this 52 comes from.

My feeling is that it's a very simple solution which I'm just unaware of, but I haven't been able to find anything on this so far, which is why I'm posting here. All help is appreciated!

-Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at some stage `np` is being converted to a string. The character `'4'` has the integer value `52`, which explains what you're getting. You've got a few options:

a) Figure out where `np` is being converted to a string and change it

b) the `%d` to a `%s`, so you get `'4'` instead of `52`

c) change the `np` part of the `printf` statement to `str2double(np)`.

Comment: Thank you for such an incredibly fast reply! You're right about the conversion to a string, and changing it using your suggestion (str2double) makes it work. 

So I wrote such an extensive post for such a simple answer.

Thanks again!